# Running MVC 4 from a Sub Folder of IIS 7

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

Is it possible to run an MVC4 project from a sub folder of IIS without setting up a virtual directory? At present I am getting the error `Directory Listing Denied This Virtual Directory does not allow contents to be listed` when trying to access the project.

The main project is called intranet which is located `\\server\inetpub\intranet` and is accessed as `http://intranet` but I have uploaded an MVC 4 project to `\\server\inetpub\intranet\affiliates\WebApplication1` but if I try to access `http://intranet/affiliates/WebApplication1` I get the error.

I am just using the default route config.

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You will start getting into messy territory of inheriting web.config from parent folders... euch.

Comment: More to the point why don't you want to run it as a virtual directory?

Comment: Were going to be looking at Areas and merging multiple MVC projects, but at present the main project is predonamtely legacy Classic ASP and access to IIS is limited without raising a support ticket.

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, you only need to setup the [sub-directory as an application](https://serverfault.com/a/358513/48172).  Be forewarned, you may run config files problems as [configuration items are inherited by parent directories](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ChangingASPNETWebconfigInheritanceWhenMixingVersionsOfChildApplications.aspx).